# View on main monitor content of second distant monitor

Tags: windows-7, display-settings

Having main monitor, and a second monitor (HD TV) situated on a considerable distance from main PC.

Is there any way/tool to see on the main monitor (maybe in small window) the content of second monitor, in order to avoid going back/forth to second monitor to check if the content is ok.

**EDIT (more explanation)**:

I need to use main monitor as main monitor, and the remote TV as remote tv, I just need to see (maybe in small window) on the main monitor what is the output on the TV now.

Video Card: Nvidia

Answer (score 1):

I see you have Nvidia. Depending on your GPU or integrated graphics, you should be able to go into the video settings and set profiles.

I would set one profile to be extended monitors, and a second as duplicate. Assign a hotkey for each profile, and use that to toggle between the two.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: thanks, but this solution is not good for my situation. Just need to see (maybe in small window) on the main monitor what is the output on the TV now

Comment: Just saw your first edit. I found some opensource software that looks like it has what you want:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html

Comment: Scalise: wow thanks, I will try it and if it works will accept the answer. I tried to google before but got nothing.

Comment: Scalise: yes, this is what I was looking for, it has "preview window". Thank you! God bless you!

Comment: Scalise: please edit your answer with information about "MultiMonitorTool", nvidia answer is not good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about fliping between main and second monitor. Please try changing the "Display Settings" of the main and second monitors.

Change this under Display Properties -> Settings -> choose the main and second monitor to rotate the display. Hope this helps.

Comment: :) I need to use main monitor as main monitor, and the remote TV as remote tv, I just need to see on the main monitor what is the output on the TV now.

Comment: My apologies..I did not read it as TV. Yes, my solution wont work.